# Как в Notepad++ найти и заменить значения в строках. Или в Python

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, notepad++

Есть текстовый файл: `userbouquet._5.tv`
В нём есть много строк - одна из них пример:

```
#SERVICE 4097:0:1:154:521:0:0:0:0:http%3a//51.195.44.53%3a8081/tv/ostros/playlist.m3u8:Остросюжетное HD
```

Постоянное в этой строке только название канала: `:Остросюжетное HD`

Это всегда меняется: `4097:0:1:154:521:0:0:0:0:http%3a//51.195.44.53%3a8081/tv/ostros/playlist.m3u8`

Постоянно присутствует этот интервал: `4097 ---- http`

Нужно найти в строку в этом файле: `userbouquet._5.tv`:

1. По названию канала: `:Остросюжетное HD`
   Я ищу эту строку так .
   Найти:
   `4097(.*?)http(.*):Остросюжетное HD`
2. Мне нужно в начале строки в этом интервале `4097 ---- http`
   Этот кусок строки `:0:1:154:521:0:0:0:0:` это всегда бывает разное.
   Заменить на постоянное исходное значение из другого файла: `EPG.txt :0:1:267:521:0:0:0:0:`

Всё остальное в найденной строке не должно изменится.

Как сделать эту замену ?

Comment: *>Мне нужно в начале строки в **этом** интервале `4097 ---- http` **Этот** кусок строки `:0:1:154:521:0:0:0:0:` **это** всегда бывает разное.* - что?? Опишите вопрос так, чтобы он был понятен не только Вам.

Comment: Начало строки:  "#SERVICE " ? или это вне строки? Если это начало строки - оно всегда одинаковое или разное? Надо ли этот кусок оставлять в начале строки?

Comment: Начало строки: "#SERVICE --- это всегда есть в начале строки, это всегда постоянное.

Answer (score 0):

Вот кусок кода который делает поиск и замену в искомых строках.
Для него надо добавить чтение строк из файла - надеюсь справитесь с чтением файла (если что- напишите, тогда я укажу что дописать для чтения (записи) файла.

итак, вот сама функция:

```
import re

def TestAndRemakeString(replasement, strsource):
    res = ''
    if re.search(r'.*4097.*http.*:Остросюжетное HD', strsource):
        ind_2 = strsource.index('http')
        ind_1 = strsource.index('4097')
        res = strsource[:ind_1 + 4:] + replasement + strsource[ind_2::]        
    return res
```

Вот как пользоваться этой функцией:

```
# str_lines - список строк для анализа и замены. формируем его из файла.
str_lines = ['#SERVICE 4097:0:1:154:521:0:0:0:0:http%3a//51.195.44.53%3a8081/tv/ostros/playlist.m3u8:Остросюжетное HD']
out_lines = []
for line in str_lines:
    result = TestAndRemakeString('-ЗДЕСЬ_УКАЗЫВАЕМ_НА_ЧТО_ЗАМЕНЯТЬ_БУДЕМ-', line)
    if result:
        # в result - строка уже с изменениями. далее делаем то, что нужно сделать с этой строкой 
        print(result)
        # например записываем в новый список:
        out_lines.append(result)
    else:
        # значит в line строка не содержащая искомой фразы здесь 
        print('Строка без изменений. Нет искомой фразы.')
        # например записываем в новый список:
        out_lines.append(line)
```

Собственно далее уже вы решаете что делать с результатом.

Comment: Уважаемый NykSu спасибо.

Comment: Уважаемый NykSu спасибо. Есть текстовый файл: userbouquet._5.tv его нужно построчно прочитать. Взять названия всех каналов  нём. Поочерёдно найти эти каналы в EPG.txt, если нашёл то заменить эту часть строки а файле: userbouquet._5.tv Далее сохранить изменение   в userbouquet._5.tv И далее следующий канал. Как Вам выслать эти файлы ?

Comment: На файлообменник можно закинуть и здесь ссылку разместить. Но я не понял что из этого есть название канала? В условии ничего не понятно.  Вы с Pythonто не знакомы совсем? Там работа с файлом то совсем простая - не сложная.

Comment: файл: userbouquet._5.tv --- здесь берём поочерёдно название канала :Остросюжетное HD Далее ищем этот канал в EPG.txt Если нашли его. То берём оттуда :0:1:267:521:0:0:0:0: ---- потом этот кусок теста вставляем в файл: userbouquet._5.tv и сохраняем

Comment: не понял что из этого есть название канала? --- не все каналы можно найти в EPG.txt Тогда его пропускаем ищем далее